# How to code print if input four word appears 3 character?

Tags: php

input name: DEVO AVIDIANTO PRATAMA output: DAP if the input three word , appears DAP

input name : RAHMA SALAM HISALAM KILA
if the input four word , appears RSH

input name: AULIA ABRAR output: AAB if the input two words, appears AAB

input name: AULIA output: AUL   if the input one word, appears AUL

```
<?php
$nama = $_POST['nama'];
$arr = explode(" ", $nama);
//var_dump($arr);die;
$jum_kata = count($arr);
//echo $jum_kata;die;
$singkatan = "";
if($jum_kata  == 1){
  //print_r($arr);
  foreach($arr as $kata)
  {
  echo substr($kata, 0,3);
  }
}else if($jum_kata == 2) {

  echo substr($arr[0],0,1);
  echo substr($arr[1],0,2);

}else {

  foreach ($arr as $kata) {
    echo  substr($kata,0,1);
  }

}

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can explode the string and then loop only three items by using array_slice.

```
$str = "RAHMA SALAM HISALAM KILA";
$word ="";

foreach(array_slice(explode(" ", $str),0,3) as $c) $word .= $c[0];
If(strlen($word) < 3) $word .= Substr($c,1,3-strlen($word));
echo $word; //RSH
```

https://3v4l.org/mhFFv

Edit missed the part about 1 or 2 words.
I added an if lenght it less than three then it should calculate how many letter to pick from the last item.

Answer (score 0):

i recommend adding the first letter into an array first

in this way you can always check if it has exceeded the 3 characters limit or not

just get some idea from the following code:

```
$output = [];
foreach($arr as $name_string){
    if (count($output) == 3){ break; }
    $output[] = $name_string;
}
echo implode("",$output);
```